# ¿Puedo definir una columna de una DB como un vector en C#?

Tags: c#, array, sqlite, tablas

Tengo una aplicación de C# con una DB de SQLite donde necesito hacer muchas tablas iguales, pero en cada tabla se guardarán datos diferentes, por ejemplo en una escuela Hay 10 grupos y quiero registrar de cada grupo, el nombre de cada alumno y la calificación de cada materia de cada alumno ¿Es posible hacer una tabla donde cada columna sea tipo matriz (Como el código de ejemplo de abajo) o es necesario hacer una tabla diferente por cada grupo?

Se que quizá no es la sintaxis correcta, pero quisiera saber si algo así es posible para ahorrar código en las 10 tablas

```
Public Class Calificaciones()
{
  [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
  int[] id = new int[10] {get; set;}
  string[] nombre = new string[10] {get; set;}
  int[] calif_español = new int[10] {get; set}
 //Aqui van las otras materias
}
```

Comment: No es posible hacer algo así. Pienso que tu pregunta es interesante, yo estuve a pasos de responderte y tratar de explicarte como lo podrías hacer, pero el código que has puesto no tiene sentido alguno `Calificaciones()` esos paréntesis no van, `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]` estos atributos ni idea de donde salen, esto que colocas así `int[] id = new int[10] {get; set;}` se escribe de esta manera `public int[] id { get; set; } = new int[10];`,

Comment: y además un `vector` es algo distinto a un `array`, entonces lamentablemente cualquier explicación que se te pueda dar no la vas a comprender

Answer (score 0):

Buen día!
Segun comprendo estas proponiendo que cada elemento de la tabla contenga particularidades.

*Lo que pides se puede realizar con bases de datos no relacionales* (MongoDB por ejemplo).

*En SQL (SQLite en este caso) toca crear las siguientes tablas*:

- **Materias** (id, Nombre)
- **Alumnos** (id, Nombre)
- **Grupos** (id, Nombre)

Adicionalmente habran 2 tablas relacionando las anteriores:

- **alumno_grupo** (idAlumno, idGrupo) (esta tabla es porque asumo que un alumno puede estar en varios grupos).
- **alumno_materia** (idAlumno, idMateria, Nota) (un alumno puede tener multiples materias)

Te recomiendo que leas documentacion o veas videos comparando base de datos mongo y sql para que entiendas la logica de cada una.